# How to make php and composer services accessible from an ubuntu container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to have an ubuntu container running with php and composer available from with in the container. From the docker documentation, it seems that Compose is provides a way to run containers alongside multiple services, below is a snippet from the docker documentation that mentions about compose

> Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications. With Compose, you use a YAML file to configure your application’s services. Then, with a single command, you create and start all the services from your configuration.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml file`

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: ubuntu
    links: 
      - db
      - kompoza
      - web_server
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
    - "3309:3306"
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_USER=user
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=demodb
  kompoza:
    image: composer
  web_server:
    image: php
```

After running `docker-compose up` all the services fire up, and instantly the `kompoza` and `web_server` services exit both with `error code 0`

[image: container first screen]
[image]

I need to be able to run `php --version` and `composer --version` inside the ubuntu container

I already know that i can install all the software i need in one container using `Dockerfile` like so

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TERM=xterm
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y curl wget php

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

But i prefer to do it the `services` way as i believe defining services give me more control

How do i achieve that ? and one more question , why did the 2 services exit but mysql didn't exit ?

Comment: Just running a bare `php` interpreter doesn't do much; as you say, it will exit immediately.  You need to write a custom `Dockerfile` – it can be `FROM php` – that `COPY`s in your application code, and run the resulting image via Compose.

Comment: @DavidMaze what you are saying is not clear. Would be helpful if you would give a more detailed explanation.